# Find Dictionary Key inside and Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array that holds several `NSMutableDictionary` objects.

Each time text fields are filled out and the submit button is pressed:

```
//The strings
NSString *dateString = @"Date";
NSString *timeString = @"Time";
NSString *typeString = @"Type";

- (IBAction)addData:(id)sender {

[_myDictionary setObject:_dateLabel.text forKey:dateString];
[_myDictionary setObject:_nNumber.text forKey:timeString];
[_myDictionary setObject:_type.text forKey:typeString];

[_myArray addObject:_myDictionary];

[self display]
}
```

Then I am trying to display the results in a UItextView (in this example the date) but I don't know how.

```
    -(void)displayData{

    for (int i = 0; i<_myArray.count; i++) {
        [_myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",[_myDictionary objectForKey:@"Date"]];

    }
    _myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",outputString];

}
```

This ends up displaying the date for the last Dictionary in the array.  I can't even figure out how to log the date from a specific dictionary.
Say `[_myArray objectAtIndex:3] [_myDictionary objectForKey:@"Date"]`.  How would I log the date from the 3rd index?

Hope this makes sense

```
EDIT SOLUTION

for (int i = 0; i<_myArray.count; i++)
    {

        outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@\n",[[_myArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Date"], [[_myArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Time"]];

    }
    _myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",outputString];

}
```

Thanks for all the quick help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int i =0 ;i <[array count];i++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]allKeys]);
 }
```

this method will print all the keys

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you have to allocate a new dictionary everytime you are adding new object to the array , otherwise your dictionary will only be holding the last value so

```
 - (IBAction)addData:(id)sender 
 {

   NSMutableDictionary *_myDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   [_myDictionary setObject:_dateLabel.text forKey:dateString];
   [_myDictionary setObject:_nNumber.text forKey:timeString];
   [_myDictionary setObject:_type.text forKey:typeString];

   [_myArray addObject:_myDictionary];

   [self display]
}
```

Now the part where so are displaying the value

```
-(void)displayData
{
   for (int i = 0; i<_myArray.count; i++) 
  {
      NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [_myArray objectAtIndexPath:i];

      outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",[dictionary objectForKey:@"Date"]];

   }
   _myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",outputString]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(void)displayData{
    NSMutableString *outputString = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in _myArray) {
        [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",dict[@"Date"]];
    }

    _myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithString:outputString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up instance and local variables, and not updating in the loop properly.

Ideally:

1. myArray will be an instance variable (like you have it now).
2. myDictionary will be a local variable in each method you need it.

This differentiates between your persistent data and your working data.

Try this instead:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Date";
NSString *timeString = @"Time";
NSString *typeString = @"Type";

- (IBAction)addData:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [dict setObject:_dateLabel.text forKey:dateString];
    [dict setObject:_nNumber.text forKey:timeString];
    [dict setObject:_type.text forKey:typeString];

    [_myArray addObject:dict];

    [self display]
}


-(void)displayData{

    NSString *outputString = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i<_myArray.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [_myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",[dict objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    }

    _myTextView.text = outputString;
}
```